# HTML file response in Pyramid

Tags: python, html, pyramid, web-frameworks, file-not-found

I am trying to adapt the to-do list app in the Pyramid tutorial [here](http://pyramid-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/single_file_tasks/single_file_tasks.html) to create a Python hangman game. My directory structure is as follows:

```
/tasks
    tasks.py
    /static
        custom.css
    /templates
        main.html
```

I want to have a single view `main.html` (i.e., just the game title, the current picture with blanks, score, etc., and a button for each letter to guess) that gets updated every time the user chooses a letter.

I figured I could do this by dynamically creating a new HTML display with each button press, similar to the jpg serving method shown [here.](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/static_assets/files.html#serving-file-content-dynamically) But upon running `python tasks.py` and opening `http://localhost:8080/#` in the browser, it gives a server error and: `"OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/templates/main.html'` in the terminal.

Here's my `tasks.py`:

```
import os
import logging

from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.events import NewRequest
from pyramid.events import ApplicationCreated
from pyramid.exceptions import NotFound
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound
from pyramid.response import FileResponse
from pyramid.view import view_config

from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger(__file__)

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='main.mako')
#def main_page(request):
#    print request #just checking
#    return {}

@view_config(route_name='home')
def main_page(request):
    response = FileResponse(os.path.join(here,'/templates/main.html'), \
                            request=request, content_type='text/html')
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = {}
    settings['reload_all'] = True
    settings['debug_all'] = True
    settings['mako.directories'] = os.path.join(here, 'templates')


    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_mako')
    config.add_route('home', '/')

    config.add_static_view('static', os.path.join(here, 'static'))

    config.scan()

    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    print 'server made'
    server.serve_forever()
```

Considering the `here` declaration, I don't see how the file can't be found. As you can see from the commented out `view_config`, I tried using my initial HTML file (renamed `main.mako`) as the renderer at first, which worked fine and displayed the main page nicely.

But I don't think I can use that to update dynamically as desired. What am I missing here? Maybe I need to add something else to the `settings` dictionary?

Comment: Adding a simple print statement somewhere should shed some light on whether the path you're passing to the FileResponse is correct or not. `print(os.path.join(here,'/templates/main.html'))`. I'm not quite sure about your overall idea of generating html files and serving them via FileResponse because, supposedly, you can't serve dynamic content with templates. Normally templates are used exactly for that - dynamically generating HTML and serving it to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You getting this error because you are using absolute path `/templates/main.html`.
Simple example how `os.path.join` works:

```
>>> os.path.join('/some/path/to/project', '/templates/main.html')
'/templates/main.html'
>>> os.path.join('/some/path/to/project', 'templates/main.html')
'/some/path/to/project/templates/main.html'
```

So try change `os.path.join(here,'/templates/main.html')` to `os.path.join(here,'templates/main.html')`.

Comment: Also `FileResponse('templates/main.html', ...)` will work.